# How to find value from arrays of object in shell script?

Tags: shell, jq

I have array of objects as given .

```
array = [{Name:'firstName', value: 'name'},
         {Name:'lastName', value: 'lname'},
         {Name:'brithDate', value: '1-1-2000'},
         {Name:'age', value: 21},]
```

How can I get the value of age from the array without for loop?
In for loop, it takes time and I want it to run in less time because I need to run this for thousands of data. Anyone has solution for it?

Comment: Is this a jq or a jquery question?  (The input is not valid JSON so I'm going to assume you meant jquery.)

Comment: This is jq in shell script

Comment: The 'array of objects' you show isn't valid json. Also `array = ` isn't jq syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that first uses [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and [hjson](/questions/tagged/hjson) to convert the text to JSON:

```
sed '1s/array =//' array.js |
 hjson -j | jq '.[] | select(.Name=="age").value'
```